# Render :json with extra data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render

I have a model called Todo and I render this:

```
format.json { render :json => @todo }
```

Each Todo belongs_to a List. I want to add the value of `@todo.list.completion_percentage` to the JSON as I need this to update the UI (AJAX request), so the JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "todo": {
    "created_at": "2011-02-26T19:39:43Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-02-26T19:53:13Z",
    "done": true,
    "text": "Apples",
    "id": 10,
    "list_id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "due_date": null



    // BELOW THIS LINE SHOULD BE IMPLEMENTED
    "list": {
      "completion_percentage": 63
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried various things but none worked. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may want to capture the value of the JSON data, and then modify it.

```
format.json { render :json => JSON::parse(@todo.to_json).merge("list" => { "completion_percentage" => 63 }).to_json }
```

Answer (score 19):

To refine Brandon's answer, try using:

```
render :json => @todo.attributes.merge({list: { "completion_percentage" => 63 }})
```

Comment: I was trying to render json for two models and got the Double Render error. Used your code to merge them and it worked perfectly. Thanks!!
    render :json => @person.attributes.merge(@vote_balance.attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Just so others are aware, calling @todo.attributes will pull off custom methods on attributes.  E.g., if you have in your Todo model a method

```
    def written_date
      self.written_date = self.written_date.utc.beginning_of_day
    end
```

And an attribute called written_date on the Todo Model, only the attribute will come back that is stored in the database.

And you expect the custom method to come back when you call `@todo.attributes`, it will not.